# Drawing a line from a point not on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

Is there a way to use `DrawLine` from an existing point on a form, lets say 500,500 to a negative point on the form (off the screen) 500, -500. 
I have not tried this before so I should probably have tried it first, but something tells me it wont work.

If I am correct is there a way to edit the `DrawLine` to take into account a negative point?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the `DrawLine` recognizes the negative aspects of the form.

This is good news for me, although I should have probably checked this before I posted, sorry community. 
I hope this helps anyone else who is unsure!